# Ler valores de uma coluna - C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, select

Preciso de ler os valores de uma coluna chamada ***Code_Article*** e coloca-los, só que quando a coluna ainda está vazia, executo e dá logo o erro:

> A referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um
>   objecto.

Aqui está o meu código:

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Code_Article FROM ArticleBarCode", conn);
Int32 codeexistente = (Int32)cmd6.ExecuteScalar();
conn.Close();
```

O que posso alterar no código para quando a coluna estiver vazia, não dar erro, mas sim retornar por exemplo 0 ?

Comment: Você continua com o problema no seu código? Porque a SQL retorna uma lista ou nenhum valor, qual é a finalidade que você precisa fazer no seu código?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro: verifique se `cmd6` não está nulo, esta é uma possibilidade.

Para sua conversão, não é uma boa ideia fazer este *cast* direto, pois o retorno de `ExecuteScalar()` pode ser `null` e isto também pode causar um erro.

Uma boa ideia é usar o `Convert.ToInt32`, isto se você tiver certeza que os valores só poderão ser `null` ou um inteiro:

```
Int32 codeexistente = Convert.ToInt32(cmd6.ExecuteScalar());
```

Se isso não pode ser garantido, o melhor a fazer é receber este resultado num `int?` e validá-lo

```
int? code = cmd6.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
Int32 codeexistente = code == null ? 0 : code;
```

O que eu simplificaria para

```
Int32 codeexistente = (cmd6.ExecuteScalar() as int?) ?? 0;
```

E também é possível fazer direto na `query`, usando o `IsNull` do SQL Server

```
SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("SELECT IsNull(Code_Article, 0) FROM ArticleBarCode", conn);
```

Comment: Continua sem funcionar com esse método, dá o mesmo erro

Comment: Então o problema é em outro lugar =D

Comment: Não sei como resolver

Comment: Bem, eu sei. Só que eu preciso saber onde é o erro. Você tem como ver qual a linha que estoura o erro?

Comment: O erro estoura na linha:  Int32 codeexistente = (Int32)cmd6.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: `cmd6` está nulo no momento do erro?

Comment: Sim, isto está dentro de um foreach e na primeira vez que o foreach executa, o cmd6 está vazio, porque só depois é que eu vou adicionar valores a essa coluna

Comment: Se `cmd6` está nulo, essa é a causa do erro.

Comment: Eu sei disso, mas a minha questão é "como é que posso resolver isso?". Porque no primeiro foreach a coluna está vazia, depois adiciono, depois no foreach seguinte, ja nao esta vazia, vai funcionar. Eu so precisava de resolver aquela parte quando a coluna está vazia no inicio

Comment: Você não está falando da mesma coisa que eu. Eu estou falando do **objeto `cmd6`**, ou seja, **o objeto referente ao comando que será executado**.

Comment: O objeto cmd6 vai trazer o valor da coluna, certo ?

Comment: Errado. Ele é o objeto do comando, o retorno é "trazido" pelo método `ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Entendi. Então sabe-me dizer como posso resolver ?

Comment: É só colocar o código realmente relevante na pergunta (isso deveria ter sido feito no início já).

Comment: Mas é este o código onde dá erro, é aqui que eu crio o cmd6, ele não aparece em mais lado nenhum !

Comment: Mas aqui nos comentários você fala em `foreach`, onde tá este `foreach`?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57898/discussion-between-d-c-and-jbueno).

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro acontece devido o retorno ser `nullo` e você tentao gravar em um inteiro, assim retorna esse erro.

Para solucionar pode utilizar o `ISNULL` do sql server, desse modo:

```
SELECT ISNULL(Code_Article,0) FROM ArticleBarCode
```

Desse modo, caso o `Code_Article` seja vazio ou `nullo` irá retornar 0 para sua aplicação.

Comment: Experimentei e não funciona na mesma, dá o mesmo erro